# Is there a way to separate out information provided in cause for exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace, catch-block

When I am printing the cause of TimeoutException caused by NoSuchElementException as in :

```
catch (TimeoutException tox) {
            tox.printStackTrace();
            printWarn("Cause for failure => " + tox.getCause());
}
```

The output to what I get from this is as follows :

> Cause for failure => org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An
>   element could not be located on the page using the given search
>   parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 10.41 seconds..
>
> **Build info**: version: '2.48.2', revision:
>   '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09
>   13:08:06'
>   **System info**: host: 'localhost', ip: '172.20.44.84', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>
> **Driver info**: AppiumDriver
>
> **Capabilities** [{....}]
>
> **Session ID**: 405d7843-5353-4a96-9288-b6d8301651b5
>
> *** **Element info**: {Using=id, value=et_mobile_editTextView}

Can I get all the information in bold separately using any property or appending any method that I might be unaware of?

What I currently have is :

```
String completeCause = tox.getCause();
```

What I am looking for is :

```
String buildInfo = tox.<somemethod>();
String driverInfo = tox.<somemethod>(); etc..
```

Thanks in advance for taking out your time to help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Selenium JavaDoc for [TimeOutException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html) shows methods `getAdditionalInformation`, `getBuildInformation`, `getDriverName`, `getSystemInformation` which will give you all your needed information separately.

```
catch(TimeoutException tox) {
  tox.printStackTrace();
  String driverName = tox.getDriverName();
  BuildInfo buildInfo = tox.getBuildInformation();
  ...
}
```

Element info is hidden in `getAdditionalInformation`. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.java#L109) of `WebDriverException` (which your exception is inheriting from) the information is stored in a private map. However, the information is seperated by `\n` which will give you the possibility to filter those entries and just search for the one with **Element Info**.

It could look like this (not tested, just written down)

```
String[] additionalInformation = tox.getAdditionalInformation().split("\n");

for(String s : additionalInformation) {
  String[] part = s.split(":");
  if("Element Info".equals(part[0]) {
    String elementInfo = part[...]; //you need to investigate the right output of the split
  }
}
```

---

[old post]

As I see `TimeOutException.getCause()` will return a `Throwable` which is in this case a `NoSuchElementException`. [Seleniums JavaDoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) reveals that there are methods `getDriverName` and `getSystemInformation`.

```
catch (TimeoutException tox) {
    tox.printStackTrace();
    if(tox.getCause() instanceof NoSuchElementException) {
      NoSuchElementException nse = (NoSuchElementException) tox.getCause();
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: went through the docs and am able to get Driver and System Info separately, but couldn't find a method for `Element info` and the information provided in the cause is what I want to breakdown into pieces

Comment: Already took a look at [TimeoutException JavaDoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html)? There are methods `getSystemInformation` and `getAdditionalInformation`. Even `getDriverName` etc. Seems the cast to `NoSuchElementException` is not necessary here.

Comment: @Ischuetze : didn't get you there

Comment: that's what I meant when I said I have tried these but couldn't find a method for `Element info`

Comment: Added code example and link to source code of the exception where you can see the details.